# About building a list until it meets conditions

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd, dcg

I wanted to solve ["the giant cat army riddle"](https://youtu.be/YeMVoJKn1Tg) by Dan Finkel using Prolog.

Basically you start with `[0]`, then you build this list by using one of three operations: adding `5`, adding `7`, or taking `sqrt`. You successfully complete the game when you have managed to build a list such that `2`,`10` and `14` appear on the list, in that order, and there can be other numbers between them.

The rules also require that all the elements are distinct, they're all `<=60` and are all only integers.
For example, starting with `[0]`, you can apply `(add5, add7, add5)`, which would result in `[0, 5, 12, 17]`, but since it doesn't have 2,10,14 in that order it doesn't satisfy the game.

I think I have successfully managed to write the required facts, but I can't figure out how to actually build the list. I think using `dcg` is a good option for this, but I don't know how.

Here's my code:

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
:- use_module(library(clpz)).
:- use_module(library(dcgs)).

% integer sqrt
isqrt(X, Y) :- Y #>= 0, X #= Y*Y.

% makes sure X occurs before Y and Y occurs before Z
before(X, Y, Z) --> ..., [X], ..., [Y], ..., [Z], ... .
... --> [].
... --> [_], ... .

% in reverse, since the operations are in reverse too.
order(Ls) :- phrase(before(14,10,2), Ls).

% rule for all the elements to be less than 60.
lt60_(X) :- X #=< 60.
lt60(Ls) :- maplist(lt60_, Ls).

% available operations
add5([L0|Rs], L) :- X #= L0+5, L = [X, L0|Rs].  
add7([L0|Rs], L) :- X #= L0+7, L = [X, L0|Rs].
root([L0|Rs], L) :- isqrt(L0, X), L = [X, L0|Rs].

% base case, the game stops when Ls satisfies all the conditions.
step(Ls) --> { all_different(Ls), order(Ls), lt60(Ls) }.

% building the list
step(Ls) --> [add5(Ls, L)], step(L).
step(Ls) --> [add7(Ls, L)], step(L).
step(Ls) --> [root(Ls, L)], step(L).
```

The code emits the following error but I haven't tried to trace it or anything because I'm convinced that I'm using DCG incorrectly:

```
?- phrase(step(L), X).
caught: error(type_error(list,_65),sort/2)
```

I'm using Scryer-Prolog, but I think all the modules are available in `swipl` too, like `clpfd` instead of `clpz`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
step(Ls) --> [add5(Ls, L)], step(L).
```

This doesn't do what you want. It describes a list element of the form `add5(Ls, L)`. Presumably `Ls` is bound to some value when you get here, but `L` is not bound. `L` would become bound if `Ls` were a non-empty list of the correct form, and you **executed** the goal `add5(Ls, L)`. But you are not executing this goal. You are storing a term in a list. And then, with `L` completely unbound, some part of the code that expects it to be bound to a list will throw this error. Presumably that `sort/2` call is inside `all_different/1`.

**Edit:** There are some surprisingly complex or inefficient solutions posted here. I think both DCGs and CLP are overkill here. So here's a relatively simple and fast one. For enforcing the correct 2/10/14 order this uses a state argument to keep track of which ones we have seen in the correct order:

```
puzzle(Solution) :-
    run([0], seen_nothing, ReverseSolution),
    reverse(ReverseSolution, Solution).
    
run(FinalList, seen_14, FinalList).
run([Head | Tail], State, Solution) :-
    dif(State, seen_14),
    step(Head, Next),
    \+ member(Next, Tail),
    state_next(State, Next, NewState),
    run([Next, Head | Tail], NewState, Solution).
    
step(Number, Next) :-
    (   Next is Number + 5
    ;   Next is Number + 7
    ;   nth_integer_root_and_remainder(2, Number, Next, 0) ),
    Next =< 60,
    dif(Next, Number).  % not strictly necessary, added by request

    
state_next(State, Next, NewState) :-
    (   State = seen_nothing,
        Next = 2
    ->  NewState = seen_2
    ;   State = seen_2,
        Next = 10
    ->  NewState = seen_10
    ;   State = seen_10,
        Next = 14
    ->  NewState = seen_14
    ;   NewState = State ).
```

Timing on SWI-Prolog:

```
?- time(puzzle(Solution)), writeln(Solution).
% 13,660,415 inferences, 0.628 CPU in 0.629 seconds (100% CPU, 21735435 Lips)
[0,5,12,17,22,29,36,6,11,16,4,2,9,3,10,15,20,25,30,35,42,49,7,14]
Solution = [0, 5, 12, 17, 22, 29, 36, 6, 11|...] .
```

The repeated `member` calls to ensure no duplicates make up the bulk of the execution time. Using a "visited" table (not shown) takes this down to about 0.25 seconds.

**Edit:** Pared down a bit further and made 100x faster:

```
prev_next(X, Y) :-
    between(0, 60, X),
    (   Y is X + 5
    ;   Y is X + 7
    ;   X > 0,
        nth_integer_root_and_remainder(2, X, Y, 0) ),
    Y =< 60.

moves(Xs) :-
    moves([0], ReversedMoves),
    reverse(ReversedMoves, Xs).
    
moves([14 | Moves], [14 | Moves]) :-
    member(10, Moves).
moves([Prev | Moves], FinalMoves) :-
    Prev \= 14,
    prev_next(Prev, Next),
    (   Next = 10
    ->  member(2, Moves)
    ;   true ),
    \+ member(Next, Moves),
    moves([Next, Prev | Moves], FinalMoves).

?- time(moves(Solution)), writeln(Solution).
% 53,207 inferences, 0.006 CPU in 0.006 seconds (100% CPU, 8260575 Lips)
[0,5,12,17,22,29,36,6,11,16,4,2,9,3,10,15,20,25,30,35,42,49,7,14]
Solution = [0, 5, 12, 17, 22, 29, 36, 6, 11|...] .
```

The table of moves can be precomputed (enumerate all solutions of `prev_next/2`, assert them in a dynamic predicate, and call that) to gain another millisecond or two. Using a CLP(FD) instead of "direct" arithmetic makes this considerably slower on SWI-Prolog. In particular, `Y in 0..60, X #= Y * Y` instead of the `nth_integer_root_and_remainder/4` goal takes this up to about 0.027 seconds.

Comment: that makes sense, I have to read up more on dcgs :)

Answer (score 4):

Given that the question seems to have shifted from using DCGs to solving the puzzle, I thought I might post a more efficient approach. I am using clp(fd) on SICStus, but I included a modified version that should work with clpz on Scryer (replacing table/2 with my_simple_table/2).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(lists)).

move(X,Y):-
    (
      X+5#=Y
    ;
      X+7#=Y
    ;
      X#=Y*Y
    ).

move_table(Table):-
    findall([X,Y],(
            X in 0..60,
            Y in 0..60,
            move(X,Y),
            labeling([], [X,Y])
         ),Table).
      

% Naive version
%%post_move(X,Y):- move(X,Y).
%%
% SICSTUS clp(fd)
%%post_move(X,Y):-
%%  move_table(Table),
%%  table([[X,Y]],Table).
%%
% clpz is mising table/2
post_move(X,Y):-
    move_table(Table),
    my_simple_table([[X,Y]],Table).

my_simple_table([[X,Y]],Table):-
      transpose(Table, [ListX,ListY]),
      element(N, ListX, X),
      element(N, ListY, Y).


post_moves([_]):-!.
post_moves([X,Y|Xs]):-
    post_move(X,Y),
    post_moves([Y|Xs]).

state(N,Xs):-
    length(Xs,N),
    domain(Xs, 0, 60),
    all_different(Xs),
    post_moves(Xs),
    % ordering: 0 is first, 2 comes before 10, and 14 is last.
    Xs=[0|_],
    element(I2, Xs, 2),
    element(I10, Xs, 10),
    I2#<I10,
    last(Xs, 14).

try_solve(N,Xs):-
    state(N, Xs),
    labeling([ffc], Xs).
try_solve(N,Xs):-
    N1 is N+1,
    try_solve(N1,Xs).


solve(Xs):-
    try_solve(1,Xs).
```

Two notes of interest:

- It is much more efficient to create a table of the possible moves and use the table/2 constraint rather than posting a disjunction of constraints. Note that we are recreating the table every time we post it, but we might as well create it once and pass it along.
- This is using the element/3 constraint to find and constraint the position of the numbers of interest (in this case just 2 and 10, because we can fix 14 to be last). Again, this is more efficient than checking the order as filtering after solving the constraint problem.

Edit:

Here is an updated version to conform to the bounty constraints (predicate names, -hopefully- SWI-compatible, create the table only once):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(lists)).

generate_move_table(Table):-
    X in 0..60,
    Y in 0..60,
    (    X+5#=Y 
    #\/  X+7#=Y 
    #\/  X#=Y*Y 
    ),
    findall([X,Y],labeling([], [X,Y]),Table).
      
%post_move(X,Y,Table):- table([[X,Y]],Table). %SICStus
post_move(X,Y,Table):- tuples_in([[X,Y]],Table). %swi-prolog
%post_move(X,Y,Table):- my_simple_table([[X,Y]],Table). %scryer

my_simple_table([[X,Y]],Table):- % Only used as a fall back for Scryer prolog
    transpose(Table, [ListX,ListY]),
    element(N, ListX, X),
    element(N, ListY, Y).

post_moves([_],_):-!.
post_moves([X,Y|Xs],Table):-
    post_move(X,Y,Table),
    post_moves([Y|Xs],Table).

puzzle_(Xs):-
    generate_move_table(Table),
    
    N in 4..61, 
    indomain(N),
    length(Xs,N),
    
    %domain(Xs, 0, 60), %SICStus
    Xs ins 0..60, %swi-prolog, scryer
    
    all_different(Xs),
    post_moves(Xs,Table),
    
    % ordering: 0 is first, 2 comes before 10, 14 is last.
    Xs=[0|_],
    element(I2, Xs, 2),
    element(I10, Xs, 10),
    I2#<I10,
    last(Xs, 14).

label_puzzle(Xs):-
    labeling([ffc], Xs).

solve(Xs):-
    puzzle_(Xs),
    label_puzzle(Xs).
```

I do not have SWI-prolog installed so I can't test the efficiency requirement (or that it actually runs at all) but on my machine and with SICStus,  the new version of the `solve/1` predicate takes 16 to 31 ms, while the `puzzle/1` predicate in Isabelle's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65513470/12100620) takes 78 to 94 ms.

As for elegance, I guess this is in the eye of the beholder. I like this formulation, it is relatively clear and is showcasing some very versatile constraints (`element/3`, `table/2`, `all_different/1`), but one drawback of it is that in the problem description the size of the sequence (and hence the number of FD variables) is not fixed, so we need to generate all sizes until one matches. Interestingly, it appears that all the solutions have the very same length and that the first solution of `puzzle_/1` produces a list of the right length.

Comment: Also, it looks like the line `domain(Xs, 0, 60)` should be changed into `Xs ins 0..60` for use with clpz.

Comment: Thanks for this! For SWI-Prolog `Xs in 0..60` in your second program must be `Xs ins 0..60`. The disjunctions in `generate_move_table/1` must use `#\/` instead of `;`, otherwise `generate_move_table/1` will succeed three times with different tables rather than with one big one. This looks like an annoying incompatibility. With these changes, `time((puzzle_(Xs), label_puzzle(Xs)))` succeeds in 0.408 seconds. My only criticism is that after `puzzle_(Xs)`, `Xs` already contains a lot of instantiated integers. It seems to me that the power here is in the precomputed table, not in constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I am sorry for both mistakes. I knew that one needs to use `ins` but just typed it wrong. And using `;` instead of `#\/` is a stupid mistake, where I moved the disjunction out of the `findall/3` at the last minute but did not realized on the spot that it was incorrect (and apparently did not test it). 

I understand the criticism, even if, to me, using table is part of the trade, and creating it is really easy. I'll think a bit more to see if I can find an alternative approach.

Comment: I think the table-based is great. It's just that once you have the table, using constraints for the rest is not essential, and indeed it's slower. Based on your solution I've hacked up a version similar to my original one but replacing `step(Head, Next)` with `member([Head, Next], Table)`, and it runs in less than 0.1 seconds here. The table is so effective at restricting and guiding the search that once you have it, brute force does the rest for you.

Comment: That's interesting (and a bit surprising) that the `member/2` call on a table with about 120 entries is faster than the call to your `step/2`. I am not familiar with `nth_integer_root_and_remainder/4`. Could this one be somehow "too slow"?

Comment: I was surprised too by the fact that a `member/2` version was so fast, but looking at the profile, it was only about 700 calls and 350 redos until the first solution is found; that's not much. I've updated my answer with another much faster version now, though I don't understand why it's so much faster than my previous one. Maybe the different state handling.

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts, I have awarded the bounty to this answer. I've realized that the reason that `puzzle_/1` instantiates integers is because propagation is so good that those integers must be known even without labeling; i.e., no labeling is required to prove that a valid solution must start `0, 5, 12`, and no valid solution can start with `0, 7, 12` for instance. This is pretty impressive! (Apart from the nice demonstration of the table technique, I still think that CLP(FD) is overkill for this problem though :-))

Comment: Thanks! I guess I agree with you that CPL(FD) is somehow overkill for this problem. But it is sometimes easier to express oneself in a formalism rather than another.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that uses `dcg` only to build the list. The `2,10,14` constraint is checked after building the list, so this is not optimal.

```
num(X) :- between(0, 60, X).

isqrt(X, Y) :- nth_integer_root_and_remainder(2, X, Y, 0). %SWI-Prolog

% list that ends with an element.
list([0], 0) --> [0].
list(YX, X) --> list(YL, Y), [X], { append(YL, [X], YX), num(X), \+member(X, YL),
                                    (isqrt(Y, X); plus(Y, 5, X); plus(Y, 7, X)) }.
soln(X) :-
    list(X, _, _, _),
    nth0(I2, X, 2), nth0(I10, X, 10), nth0(I14, X, 14),
    I2 < I10, I10 < I14.
```

```
?- time(soln(X)).
% 539,187,719 inferences, 53.346 CPU in 53.565 seconds (100% CPU, 10107452 Lips)
X = [0, 5, 12, 17, 22, 29, 36, 6, 11, 16, 4, 2, 9, 3, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 42, 49, 7, 14]
```

Comment: 5 -> 2 is not a valid transition. You need to force the remainder to be 0 in `isqrt/2`.

Comment: sorry about that, I should've clarified that sqrt only works on integer square numbers, such as 4,9,16..

Comment: Sry didn't look at your code. I assumed `isqrt` to mean what it usually does.

Comment: Changing to `sqrt` the rest of the code still works.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a little [magic set](http://users.informatik.uni-halle.de/%7Ebrass/lp07/c7_magic.pdf). The predicate path/2 does search a path without giving us a path. We can therefore use commutativity of +5 and +7, doing less search:

```
step1(X, Y) :- N is (60-X)//5, between(0, N, K), H is X+K*5,
         M is (60-H)//7, between(0, M, J), Y is H+J*7.
step2(X, Y) :- nth_integer_root_and_remainder(2, X, Y, 0).

:- table path/2.
path(X, Y) :- step1(X, H), (Y = H; step2(H, J), path(J, Y)).
```

We then use path/2 as a magic set for path/4:

```
step(X, Y) :- Y is X+5, Y =< 60.
step(X, Y) :- Y is X+7, Y =< 60.
step(X, Y) :- nth_integer_root_and_remainder(2, X, Y, 0).

/* without magic set */
path0(X, L, X, L).
path0(X, L, Y, R) :- step(X, H), \+ member(H, L), 
   path0(H, [H|L], Y, R).

/* with magic set */
path(X, L, X, L).
path(X, L, Y, R) :- step(X, H), \+ member(H, L), 
   path(H, Y), path(H, [H|L], Y, R).
```

Here is a time comparison:

```
SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.3.16)

/* without magic set */
?- time((path0(0, [0], 2, H), path0(2, H, 10, J), path0(10, J, 14, L))), 
   reverse(L, R), write(R), nl.
% 13,068,776 inferences, 0.832 CPU in 0.839 seconds (99% CPU, 15715087 Lips)
[0,5,12,17,22,29,36,6,11,16,4,2,9,3,10,15,20,25,30,35,42,49,7,14]

/* with magic set */
?- abolish_all_tables.
true.

?- time((path(0, [0], 2, H), path(2, H, 10, J), path(10, J, 14, L))), 
   reverse(L, R), write(R), nl.
% 2,368,325 inferences, 0.150 CPU in 0.152 seconds (99% CPU, 15747365 Lips)
[0,5,12,17,22,29,36,6,11,16,4,2,9,3,10,15,20,25,30,35,42,49,7,14]
```

Noice!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it without DCG's, it takes about 50 minutes on my machine to solve for the length N=24. I suspect this is because the `order` check is done for every list from scratch.

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
:- use_module(library(clpz)).
:- use_module(library(dcgs)).
:- use_module(library(time)).

%% integer sqrt
isqrt(X, Y) :- Y #>= 0, X #= Y*Y.

before(X, Y, Z, L) :-
        %% L has a suffix [X|T], and T has a suffix of [Y|_].
        append(_, [X|T], L),
        append(_, [Y|TT], T),
        append(_, [Z|_], TT).

order(L) :- before(2,10,14, L).

game([X],X).
game([H|T], H) :- ((X #= H+5); (X #= H+7); (isqrt(H, X))), X #\= H, H #=< 60, X #=< 60,  game(T, X). % H -> X.

searchN(N, L) :- length(L, N), order(L), game(L, 0).
```

Comment: If you try to use element/3 instead of append/3, it should be faster. E.g. before(X, Y, Z, L) :-
        length(L,Len),
        element(Len,L,Z),        
        element(XIx,L,X),
        element(YIx,L,Y),
        XIx #< YIx.
Using SWI-Prolog's clpfd this went from about 124s to about 36s: http://hakank.org/swipl/giant_cat_army_riddle.pi . (My Picat variant of your approach takes 1.4s. A better Picat CP approach takes 0.2s: http://hakank.org/picat/giant_cat_army_riddle.pi )

Comment: Thank you for the links, the cp solution is both fast and easy to understand. I learned about Picat just a few days ago and I must say it really picked my interest. It sounds like a wonderful language to do constraint programming.

Comment: Glad you tried Picat, it's a really great language. By the way, I tweaked the Picat CP approach a little more (go4/0), and now iẗ́'s 0.028s: http://hakank.org/swipl/giant_cat_army_riddle.pi